# How to properly create a new state in Redux?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

Working with Redux in my Angular app, and simply creating a new state in each Case inside the **Switch Statement**. However, even though my code works just fine I don't feel comfortable with the way **I'm cloning my object** inside each case, so is there a **better** or **cleaner** way of cloning it? How can I improve the **Case** statement? Thanks in advance!.

Here's my

**Interface:**

```
export interface AppState {
  session: {},
  uiState: {
    summary: {
      summaryDetail: {
        headerTitle: string;
        expandSummaryDetailPanel: boolean;
        showSummaryDetail: boolean;
        someProperty: string;
       }
       showSummaryTab: boolean;
    }
  }
};
```

**Initial State:**

```
export const initialState: AppState = {
  session: {},
  uiState: {
    summary: {
      summaryDetail: {
        headerTitle: 'new title',
        expandSummaryDetailPanel: false,
        showSummaryDetail: false,
        someProperty: ''
      },
      showSummaryTab: false,
    }
  }
};
```

**Switch Statement:**

```
export function appReducer(state = initialState, action: appActions.AppAction) { 

 case appActions.EXPAND_SUMMARY_DETAIL_PANEL: {
  return {
    ...state,
    uiState: {
      summary: {
        ...state.uiState.summary,
        summaryDetail: {
          ...state.uiState.summary.summaryDetail,
          expandSummaryDetailPanel: action.payload
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need additional libraries to avoid repeating the nesting **if** your state actually has to be this deeply nested. **I'd try to model the state differently (flatter) first**. But if that is somehow not an option, you can do this:

```
case appActions.EXPAND_SUMMARY_DETAIL_PANEL:
    // Find a library that clones objects or use something like immutablejs.
    const newState = deepClone(state);
    newState.uiState.summary.summaryDetail.expandSummaryDetailPanel = action.payload;
    return newState;
```

A few notes:

- The properties in your state repeat the word "summary" a lot. Would `state.summary.detail.expandPanel` also work and be expressive enough?
- `uiState` reads like you're expressing **where** the state is used, but redux doesn't have to be concerned about this. This type of mapping happens in `mapStateToProps`. Or at the very least shorten it to `state.ui`.